# How can I tell the asymptotes for this function?

Tags: calculus, functions

Given $g(x) = \tan^{-1}(x) + \frac{3x}{x-2}$, how can I know the vertical and horizontal asymptotes for $g(x)$?

Without the $\tan^{-1}(x)$, I know there would be vertical asymptote at $x=2$. After graphing it out using computer, it seems to have preserved this.

However, without $\tan^{-1}(x)$, $g(x)$ seems to have a horizontal asymptote at $y=3$. But with $\tan^{-1}(x)$, I cannot tell. Can anyone please explain what I should do to properly determine the asymptotes of $g(x)$?

Answer (score 4):

Domain of $f(x)$ is all real numbers excepting $x=2.$
$f(x)$ can assume any real value near $x=2$, so its range is $(-\infty, \infty).$ The asymptotes are $y=\pm \pi/2$ and $x=2$.

Comment: If it has horizontal asymptotes at $y=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$, then why is its range $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: Because near $x-2$ it takes any large positive/negative values.

Answer (score 1):

The field of existence of the independent variable $x$ is all the real field except $x=$2.
The field of existence of the variable dependent $y$ is all the real field except

$y=3+\frac{\pi}{2}$,

and

$y=3-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The function has two horizontal asymptotes,

(a) when x tends to + infinity its value is:
$\lim_{x\to+∞}\left( \tan^{-1}(x) + \frac{3x}{x-2}\right)=3+\frac{\pi}{2}$:

line parallel to the axis of the abscisses of equation:

$y=3+\frac{\pi}{2}$,

(b) when $x$ tends to – infinity the value is:
$\lim_{x\to-∞}\left( \tan^{-1}(x) + \frac{3x}{x-2}\right)=3-\frac{\pi}{2}$:
$

line parallel to the axis of the abscisses of equation:

$y=3-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The vertical asymptoth is $x=$2.